# How to merge and sort two doubly linked lists in C

Tags: c, merge, linked-list, mergesort, doubly-linked-list

I am currently working on a project that takes in two text files with data and sorts them into two separate linked lists. My next step is to create a function that takes in those two lists to merge and sort them by ID in increasing order. I have started the implementation but I am stuck and need some guidance on what it is I am doing wrong for the merge sort function. Everything else is working correctly such as sorting each list individually. I just need a way to take in those two lists and merge sort them together in C. Note: I am using the Ubuntu gcc compiler.

```
struct List *merge_list(struct List *list1, struct List *list2)
{
    struct Node *hand1 = list1->head;
    struct Node *hand2 = list2->head;
    struct Node *tmp1, *tmp2 = NULL;
    struct List *list3 = malloc(sizeof(struct List));

    while(list1 && list2 != NULL)
    {
            if(ptr1->id > ptr2->id)
            {
                    ptr1 = list3->head;
                    ptr1 = ptr1->next;
            }
            else
            {
                    ptr2 = list3->head;
                    ptr2 = ptr2->next;
            }
    }
    return list3;
}
```

Note: Here are my Node and List structs

```
struct Node {
  int id;
  char *fname;
  char *lname;
  char *department;
  float gpa;
  struct Node *next;
  struct Node *prev;
};

struct List {
  struct Node *head;
  struct Node *tail;
  int count;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To merge two sorted lists:

```
while (hand1 && hand2) {
    if (hand1->id <= hand2->id) {
        tmp = hand1;
        hand1 = hand1->next;
    } else {
        tmp = hand2;
        hand2 = hand2->next;
    }

    insertNode(list3, tmp);
}

// either hand1 or hand2 will have some leftover elements
// they can be added to the back of list by inserting the head
if (hand1)
    insertNode(list3, hand1);
else
    insertNode(list3, hand2);
```

I've left it to you to write insertNode().  In order to preserve the sorting of the two lists, it should insert nodes at the end of the list.  It should be very easy since you are tracking the tail of the list.

I would initialize the pointers in list3 to NULL and the count to 0, it should make writing insertNode() easier.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I do have an Insert Tail function for inserting a Node at the end of a list. Here is what it looks like: (next comment)

Comment: void insert_tail(struct Node *node, struct List *list) {
    if(list->head == NULL && list->tail == NULL) {
      list->head = node;
      list->tail = node;
    } else {
      list->tail-> next = node;
      node->prev = list->tail;
      list->tail = node;
      list->count+=1;
    }
}                                                                                                                  I implemented your way of doing it and I am still receiving a segmentation fault, any idea why it would be doing that?

Comment: Hmm, I just threw it all in Visual Studio and it seemed to work fine for me.  The only difference is that my list is only single-linked, so I took out the one line in your insert_tail() which set the prev pointer.  Here's a gist with my complete file:   [merge_linked_lists.c](https://gist.github.com/sdocy/e6a489608f976784d6bafd2d9ad0772c)

Answer (score 0):

You have two doubly linked list and both are sorted and your requirement is to create a function that takes in those two lists to merge and sort them by ID in increasing order. Since both the doubly linked list is already sorted, you don't need to first merge them and then sort but you can merge them in sorted order.

You can do:

```
struct Node * merge_list(struct Node * head1, struct Node * head2)
{   
    struct Node* head3 = NULL;
    struct Node* p1 = head1;
    struct Node* p2 = head2;
    struct Node* p3 = NULL;

    while (p1 != NULL || p2 != NULL)
    {   
        struct Node * tmp = NULL;
        if (p1 == NULL) {
            tmp = p2;
            p2 = NULL;
        } else if (p2 == NULL) {
            tmp = p1;
            p1 = NULL;
        }

        if ((p1 != NULL) && (p2 != NULL)) {
            if (p1->id < p2->id) {
                tmp = p1;
                p1 = p1->next;
            } else {
                tmp = p2;
                p2 = p2->next;
            }
        }

        if (head3 == NULL) {
            head3 = tmp;
        } else {
            p3->next = tmp;
            tmp->prev = p3;
        }
        p3 = tmp;
    }
    return head3;
}
```

Output:

```
List 1:
1  3  7
List 2:
2  4  6  8 
Merged list:
1  2  3  4  6  7  8
```

Few points about `merge_list()` function:

- In this `merge_list()` function I am taking the `head` pointers of both the list and returning the `head` pointer of the merged list. But I can see that you have `struct List` which maintains the `head` and `tail` pointer of the lists. So, you need to do the changes accordingly in the function, like the argument and return type will be `struct List *` type and in the function, you need to take care of merge list `tail` pointer as well. The core logic is going to be same.
- The function `merge_list()` modify the two list, which are passed as arguments to it, as it resets the `next` and `prev` pointers of the lists node in order to merge them. So, after this function call, both the lists passed as arguments to it are no more valid. Set their `head` and `tail` pointer to `NULL`.
- If you want both the list, passed as arguments to `merge_list()`, intact after the `merge_list()` call then you need to make copy of node while adding to the merged list. For that, you need to allocate memory to `tmp` and wherever `tmp` is set to either `p1` or `p2`, instead assign the values to `tmp` members. Be cautious here, if a member of the structure `Node` is a pointer to some memory then allocate memory to that `tmp` member pointer and copy the value.

Hope this helps.